# Java Average, Jumps

Tags: java

I'm a complete Java newbie. Started Last Monday and have never done any programming in any language before. So please bear with me if I find easy things complicated.

I've been given a text file. As shown below:

The First piece of data is time (in seconds past midnight), the second is score (irrelevant), the third is Jump (dont need to know what this means...)

I can happily read this in using this code:

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;



 public class ReadText {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   String InputFile="C:\\PracticeSpreads.txt";
   ArrayList<String> fileLines=new ArrayList<String>();
   FileReader fr;
   BufferedReader br;
   fr = new FileReader(InputFile);
   br = new BufferedReader(fr);
   String line;
   br.readLine();

   while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {

   fileLines.add(line);

   //System.out.print(line+"\n");



 }

 }
 }
```

I skipped the first line because it makes it easier.

Ok basically what I need to do is create a Daily Time weighted Average Jump.

I can get an average Jump but not a time weighted average Jump.

The formula for time weighted average jump is=

For times when a second has more than one Jump, I want to take the "average jump" for that time period.

But I've literally got no idea as I'm not too sure as to how the loops would arrange themselves.

Hopefully someone can help me please!

Comment: This sounds like a school assignment, isn't it?

Comment: Talk to your instructor or read a book. We can't teach you elementary programming here.

Comment: I'm at University which finished a month ago and starts again in October. 

I'm working for my Dad's self-employed business rather than him having to get in an IT technician.

Comment: You shouldn't delete the question after it's solved, they can be useful for other people.

Answer (score 1):

After reading your comments bellow and understanding your requirement better, here is a piece of code that does the job. Note that it assumes that the timestamps in each day are sorted, as in your example:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;

public class ReadText {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try {
            String InputFile = "C:\\PracticeSpreads.txt";
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(InputFile));
            String line;
            List<SimpleEntry<Integer, List<Double>>> valuesInDay = new ArrayList<SimpleEntry<Integer, List<Double>>>();
            String date = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                line = line.trim();
                if (line.startsWith("DATE")) {
                    if (line.equals(date)) // Found day footer
                        System.out.println("Average for " + date + ": " + calcDayAvg(valuesInDay));
                    else { // Found a day header
                        valuesInDay.clear();
                        date = line;
                    }
                } else { // Found a value entry
                    Scanner s = new Scanner(line);
                    int sec = s.nextInt();
                    s.nextDouble();
                    double jump = s.nextDouble();

                    List<Double> jumps;
                    if (!valuesInDay.isEmpty() && valuesInDay.get(valuesInDay.size() - 1).getKey() == sec) {
                        // Same time stamp as prev
                        jumps = valuesInDay.get(valuesInDay.size() - 1).getValue();
                    }else { 
                        // New time stamp
                        jumps = new ArrayList<Double>();                        
                        valuesInDay.add(new SimpleEntry<Integer, List<Double>>(sec, jumps));
                    }
                    jumps.add(jump);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if (br != null)
                br.close();
        }
    }

    private static Double calcDayAvg(List<SimpleEntry<Integer, List<Double>>> values) {
        if (values.isEmpty())
            return null; // No way to calculate for empty set
        double min = values.get(0).getKey();
        double max = values.get(values.size() - 1).getKey();
        double span = max - min;
        if (span == 0)
            return null; // Division by zero...     

        double total = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < values.size(); i++) {
            SimpleEntry<Integer, List<Double>> entry = values.get(i);
            int sec = entry.getKey();
            double jumpAvg = getJumpAvg(entry.getValue());
            int jumpDuration;
            if (i == values.size() - 1)
                jumpDuration = 1; // last jump has duration of 1 sec
            else
                jumpDuration = values.get(i + 1).getKey() - sec;

            total += jumpAvg * jumpDuration;
        }
        return total / span;
    }

    private static double getJumpAvg(List<Double> jumps) {
        double total = 0;
        for (Double jump : jumps) {
            total += jump;
        }
        return total / jumps.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, this isn't homework. University is finished for the year...I'm working for my Dad's business, I said I'd take this on rather than him having to get in an IT technician. This is the only thing holding me back, so if I can get this code I can get on with the rest of the project.

A I said I started last Monday, so unfortunately, as hard as I'm trying, I don't really understand what you just said? I find Java interesting, and when uni starts up again in October I'm going to take a course in it, but for the moment I'm just trying to get things done as soon as possible!

Comment: @Sam Hank: Sorry for misunderstanding :) I'll update the answer and attach some code. Anyway, you'll have to learn the basics of programming and the basics of Java in order to be productive in this project. Did you consider using Excel for this project instead of Java?

Comment: Thanks! I would happily use excel, but the text file is huge. So I thought it best to try and get a code that works for a small file, because then that would work on a large file? (I hope!.. haha)

Once this is sorted I won't need to use Java much again I think, it's more of comparing it to past data and seeing how it's changed. Then just gna tell my dad what's different and he'll take it from there! 

Thanks for your help, massively appreciated!!

Comment: Thanks Eyal, that would be great

Comment: @Sam: I assume that the "time at the jump" in the formula is an offset from the minimum value of that day, am I right? (That means that the first value in each day has no influence on the average)

Comment: @Sam: why is the first jump duration 2 and not 628 (28828-28200)?

Comment: My fault again, I was looking at the wrong line. You're right!

Comment: @Sam: Your question really misses some important points regarding your requirement. I changed the code. I hope it is helpful now.